# Bootstrap-UI local images not showing

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm using AngularJS with Bootstrap-UI and I'm using the carousel directive.  When I have the images in my Ctrl pointing to a website (lorumpixel.com) the images are appearing; however, I have images that I want to place into the site.

```
<div ng-controller="CarouselCtrl">
  <div carousel interval="3000">
    <div slide ng-repeat="slide in slides" active="slide.active">
      <img ng-src="{{slide.image}}">
      <div class="carousel-caption animated slideInLeft">
        <h2>Slide {{$index}}</h2>
        <p>{{slide.text}}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and my Controller

```
'use strict';

angular.module('angularApp')
  .controller('CarouselCtrl', function ($scope) {

    $scope.slides = [];
    $scope.slides.push({text: '', image: 'images/bg-2.jpg'});

    $scope.setActive = function(idx) {
      $scope.slides[idx].active=true;
    };
  });
```

I'm hoping to get this website up by the end of the week so any help is greatly appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have now tried changing the path to the file and I still am not getting a result.  I've tried: angular/app/images/bg-2.jpg, app/images/bg-2.jpg, even  ../images/bg-2.jpg. Still getting a 404 error.

Comment: try the full qualified URL e.g. `<img ng-src="http://www.example.com/images/{{slide.image}}"/>`

Comment: I've tried that as well.  Right now I'm working locally, so this might be an issue when the site goes live.  Appreciate you help.

Comment: If you use a local web server try with `<img ng-src="http://localhost/images/{{slide.image}}"/>`. Also try to open the image directly in the browser to ensure it is served by the web server.

Comment: Still no dice.  I've verified the image is accessible at: http://127.0.0.1:9000/images/bg-2.jpg.  I'm sooo confused and frustrated.

Comment: then `<img ng-src="http://127.0.0.1:9000/{{slide.image}}"/>` should work. Given you have `images/bg-2.jpg` in `slide.image`.

Answer (score 0):

```
roof.controller.js 

angular.module('monsterApp').controller('CarouselCtrl', function ($scope) {
  $scope.myInterval = 5000;
  $scope.noWrapSlides = false;
  var slides = $scope.slides = [];
  $scope.addSlide = function() {
    var newWidth = 1500 + slides.length + 1;
    slides.push({
        url:  "http://res.cloudinary.com/dqa0blkfn/image/upload/v1436283760/monster-head_tnxloc.jpg",
   /*   url: '//placekitten.com/' + newWidth + '/300',      */

      text: [' ',' ',' ',' '][slides.length % 4] + ' ' +
      ['    ', '    ', '  ', '   '][slides.length % 4]
    });
  };



roof.html


<div ng-controller="CarouselCtrl">
    <div style="height: 305px">
      <carousel interval="myInterval" no-wrap="noWrapSlides">
        <slide ng-repeat="slide in slides" active="slide.active">
          <img ng-src="{{slide.url}}" style="margin:auto;">
          <div class="carousel-caption">
            <h4>Slide {{$index}}</h4>
            <p>{{slide.text}}</p>
          </div>
        </slide>
      </carousel>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" ng-click="addSlide()">Add Slide</button>
        <div class="checkbox">
          <label>
            <input type="checkbox" ng-model="noWrapSlides">
            Disable Slide Looping
          </label>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        Interval, in milliseconds: <input type="number" class="form-control" ng-model="myInterval">
        <br />Enter a negative number or 0 to stop the interval.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: use a cdn if you can for when the site goes live amazon bitbucket or cloudinary cdn :) Solution was to add slide.url to ng-src and in the controller instead of image: '//placekitten.com/' + newWidth + '/300',      use  url:  "http://res.cloudinary.com/dqa0blkfn/image/upload/v1436283760/monster-head_tnxloc.jpg",

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it would be better to include some context, explaining how it works and when to use it. Code-only answers are not useful in the long run.